# NSMutableArray addObject returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

There are some similar questions that already exist on StackOverflow. I did check them out, and in most cases it returns nil because the `NSMutableArray` has not been initialised. But in my case I did initialise it.

Here's part of my code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.storedTimeZones = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSData *storedData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:@"timeZones"];

    if (storedData != nil ) {
        self.storedTimeZones = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedData];
    }

    NSString *str = [self.smallRegionArray[indexPath.row] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
    [self.storedTimeZones addObject: str];
    NSLog(str); //the string was printed successfully.
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.storedTimeZones.count); //'0' was printed
}
```

**update**
@Caleb was right, `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedData` returned nil. I solved it by doing this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.storedTimeZones = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSData *storedData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:@"timeZones"];
    NSMutableArray *ary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedData];

    if (ary != nil ) {
        self.storedTimeZones = ary;
    }

    NSString *str = [self.smallRegionArray[indexPath.row] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
    [self.storedTimeZones addObject: str];
    NSLog(str);
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.storedTimeZones.count); //Now it prints `1`
}
```

Comment: It doesn't throw an *unrecognized selector* exception?

Comment: @trojanfoe lol now I got the unrecognized selector exception

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped, but you still have a big bug: `unarchiveObjectWithData` will give you an immutable array. If you expect `self.storedTimeZones` to be mutable, you should make a mutable copy: `[[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedData] mutableCopy]`

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for reminding. I added `mutableCopy` as you suggested but still got the `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error when I run it. (just like what @trojanfoe predicted)

Comment: @AlexLing Again, you'll want to examine the actual object that `self.storedTimeZones` points to. I provided debugger commands in my answer. When you know what type of object you're dealing with, you'll understand why you're getting the exception and you should be able to figure out how you get that object instead of the mutable array that you expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But in my case I did initialise it.

You did, but then you replaced it. Here's the initializing line:

```
self.storedTimeZones = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

but then you assign a different value:

```
self.storedTimeZones = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedData];
```

and at this point, `self.storedTimeZones` may be either a non-mutable instance of `NSArray`, or some entirely different object, or `nil`. I'd guess it's the latter since no exception is thrown when you call `-addObject:`. That the `count` is 0 also makes sense if `self.storedTimeZones` is `nil`, since the result of messaging `nil` is `nil` or `0` or `NO`, depending on what type you expect.

All you really need to do to properly diagnose the problem is to examine `self.storedTimeZones` near your last `NSLog` statement. Set a breakpoint and look at the contents of that property. Useful commands will be:

```
po self.storedTimeZones
po [self.storedTimeZones class]
```

Comment: I agree, but that doesn't tally with the error the OP is seeing.

Comment: @trojanfoe What error is the OP seeing? He (or she?) doesn't tell us.

Comment: That it "returns nil", which doesn't make sense.  However it's not the same as an exception (which I was expecting), which is somewhat "in your face".

Comment: @trojanfoe I didn't get any error. The only problem is the nil result.

Comment: I can only imagine that `unarchiveObjectWithData` is returning `nil`.  If it wasn't then an exception is certain. EDIT: which you've already mentioned.

Comment: @trojanfoe at which line do you think should throw a exception?

Comment: Follow this answer.  It contains all the information.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign the object to the entire mutable array, you're not adding a object to it.

That's not the way it works.

Try this:

`[self.storedTimeZones addObject:
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedData]];`

Or this

`[self.storedTimeZones addObjectsFromArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedData]];`

Or this

`self.storedTimeZones = [NSArray alloc]; // Note: not a mutable array
[self.storedTimeZones initWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedData]];`

You've never told us if the contents of the keyedUnarchiver is an array, but we expect it is.

In either case, if this is the only time you add info to the array, you don't need to make it mutable.

Good luck.

Comment: Your first option will add the array itself, not the items in the array.